# Index with Multiple Returns

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

I am trying to create a formula that will take a value from A2, A3, A4 etc and search another spreadsheet to return multiple values based on what is in A2, I have managed to create an array formula as per below, the lookup does work and lists all of the relevant values however for some reason it keeps skipping the first value that it should return and goes straight to the second value, please help!

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$B:$B, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C))+1, ""), ROW(A2))),"")
```

Comment: change the `ROW(A2)` at the end to `ROW(A1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner THANK YOU!!!